# I got warning when upload any csv file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I want to upload CSV file to mysql database but i got error  can any one help me please i am new in php
**Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: Filename cannot be empty**

Here Is code please help me

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
mysql_select_db("csv",$connect);
?> 
<?php
//Upload File
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
echo "<h3>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." ."</h3>";

}
//Import uploaded file to Database
$handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");
$firstRow = true;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
if($firstRow) { $firstRow = false; }
else {
$import="INSERT into product_details(pname,price,total) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]')";

mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}

fclose($handle);

print "Import done";
```

}else { ?>

```
<h3>Upload new csv by Browsing to file and Clicking on Upload</h3><br />

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action='' method='post'>

    <input type="file" name="filename" onchange="checkfile(this);" ><br /><br />
    <input class="btn btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

In advance thanks

Comment: First, you should save the file uploaded. then the path can be read with fopen

Comment: Did you check the `$_POST` variable?